# order of x relatively prime to N

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Will it be true that for any composite number $N$ with $$N=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_m^{\alpha_m}$$ ($p_i$: odd prime, $\alpha_i\geq1$, $m\geq2$) and any $x$ with $$\gcd(x,N)=1$$ satisfies
$$x^{\frac{\phi(N)}{2^{m-1}}}\equiv1\mod N$$? ($\phi(N)$ is Euler's phi function.)
It can be thought as an extension for Euler's theorem.. and for some simple cases N=15, 33, 35, 45, and 105 it was true. Will it be true for all N and x?

Comment: Verified up to $N=1000$, even for $m=1$. (When $m=1$, it is just Fermat's little theorem.)

Comment: By definition, the least positive $k$ such that $x^k \equiv 1 \mod n$ for all $x$ coprime to $n$ is Carmichael's Function $k=\lambda(n)$.  Your goal should be to look for when $\lambda(N)$ does not evenly divide $\frac{\phi(N)}{2^{m-1}}$, and that will yield a counterexample.  If it always divides it, then you're good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true. It is enough to show that for any $i$, we have 
$$x^{\frac{\varphi(N)}{2^{m-1}}}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i^{\alpha_i}}.\tag{1}$$
For notational simplicity, let $i=1$. Note that
$$\varphi(N)=\varphi(p_1^{\alpha_1})\prod_2^m \varphi(p_j^{\alpha_j}).$$
The $\varphi(p_j^{\alpha_j})$ are all even, so 
$$\varphi(N)=\varphi(p_1^{\alpha_1})2^{m-1}K$$
for some integer $K$.

Thus $\frac{\varphi(N)}{2^{m-1}}$ is a multiple of $\varphi(p_1^{\alpha_1})$, and Congruence 1 follows by Euler's Theorem.

*Remark*: For a generalization, please search under *Carmichael function*.